# Failed to generate application.xml

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm trying to build ear with the command

> mvn clean install

This is the error I got

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10.1:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project my_project_name_ear: Failed to generate application.xml: Exception while opening file[D:\amt_bo\my_project_name_ear\target\applicati
>   on.xml]: D:\amt_bo\my_project_name_ear\target\application.xml (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]

**But if I run build again it successively builds.**

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml file?

Comment: I think it's against my company policies.
I think the problem is with my machine because of  **(Access is denied)** message.
I'm using a windows 10 pc ( 1909 )

Answer (score 1):

Delete .m2\repository folder under C:\Users (or D:) and then retry clean install.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.
Do I need to do that before every clean install?

Comment: nope, just once. and check if there is any username password requirement to connect to your repositories, because it says "Access is denied" .

Comment: It cant be the problem because if I run the same command again it works.

Comment: That will not help.

Comment: So, are you saying that you run `mvn clean install` and it ends with that error, and then you run `mvn clean install` again and the error is gone?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici it's not working, Issue stills the same!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple reasons can be there as network issues, machine OS issues etc.

- You have to make sure that the mentioned jar is in your m2 folder.
- Go to your .m2 folder and the mentioned path in the error.
- m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-ear-plugin\2.10.1 there should be a jar file named maven-ear-plugin-2.10.
- If it is not available, download it from https://mvnrepository.com/ or copy from someone already have.
- If it is already there, Try with CMD as administrator. It resolves many permissions denied errors.
- Usually that is the way to solve this kind of errors.